# FTDI device not working WSL with usbipd-win

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04, ftdi, usbipd

I try to use a FTDI device (0403:6010) on a Windows 10 PC using WSL.

For that I follow instructions given there and instal usbipd-win successfully:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb

On the WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04), I installed the FTDI driver (v 1.4.27) following installation instructions here: https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux-1.pdf

Everything looks good, except that I get an error on FT_Open() returning FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED.

Note that on FTDI installation instructions, it is advised to remove the ftdi_sio module. But I get an error when attempting to do it on my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 distribution :

```
$ sudo rmmod ftdi_sio
rmmod: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1941 kmod_module_get_holders() could not open '/sys/module/ftdi_sio/holders': No such file or directory
rmmod: ERROR: Module unloading is not supported
```

Could this error be related to my issue ?

Comment: Same here. Have you ever solved? Thanks!