Connecting and receive data from a serial USB port to WSL 2
I have a problem encountered while connecting a USB serial port to windows and trying to get data from that port into WSL2.
The problem is that I can list usb devices in windows powershell
PS C:\> usbipd list
results in:
BUSID  VID:PID    DEVICE                 STATE
6-4    0403:6001  USB Serial Converter   Attached
I can attach the USB to WSL by using
PS C:\> usbipd attach --wsl --busid 6-4

It is attached to WSL.

From WSL side, I can show usb connections in WSL by lsusb, giving:

To check the device name:
sudo dmesg | grep tty

gives this:


From the Python side, I want to communicate with the serial port to get data etc. The code is:
import serial 
import time 
import time 
import os

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')   # device name on your computer 

print(ser.name) # check which port was really used
ser.write(b'serail port on wsl \n') # write a string
s = ser.readline()
print(s)
ser.close()

This code cannot write nor readline() and does not give any output, so basically it is not reading any data from the serial port.

I have checked some issues but those did not solve my problems, here-1, here-2, here-3, here-4.
Is there anything I can further investigate and solve this issue?

Likely, the kernel does not include the FTDI driver. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76341080/ftdi-device-not-working-wsl-with-usbipd-win and https://www.ralf-lang.de/2024/04/02/run-ftdi-usb-devices-on-windows-10-11-wsl2/. You will need to build and install a custom kernel.

The problem is simply solved by defining baudrate as 460800 in serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate).
